# Why can't I do a simple u-substitution with $\int \sin(\sqrt{x}) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

When looking at this problem, I was thinking I could do a simple u-sub.

$$ \int \sin(\sqrt{x}) dx $$

I was thinking I could set $$ u = \sqrt(x) $$
    $$ u^2 = x $$
Then I would set $$ du = dx $$

Then I could simple integrate $\sin$ into $-\cos$

as well as $u^2$ into $\dfrac{u^3}{3} $

The I could simply sub x back into the equation

$$ -\cos\left(\frac{x^{2/3}}{3}\right) + c $$

But this yields the wrong answer. So I'm assuming I need to do integration by parts.

Edit: After reworking it with the new info, I've come out with

$$ 2\left[-\sqrt{x}\cos(\sqrt{x}) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right] + c $$

Comment: If $u^2 = x$, then $dx = 2u\,du$.

Comment: It is frustrating that I keep making this simple mistakes! I guess I just need to keep practicing! Thanks Daniel, I'll rework it with this.

Comment: @Adobe Please stop doing this kind of minor edits.

Comment: @O.L. Could you clarify please how adding 'tags' are minor edits?

Comment: @Adobe Do you understand that by adding tags (which is obviously a minor edit, less minor simply does not exist) you have filled the main page by old answered questions whereas relatively new questions become invisible?

Comment: @O.L. You can sort out questions by 'date': http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: @Adobe I (and surely many other users) will not change my way of using the site just because you decided to make 50 edits in 30 minutes.

Comment: @O.L. My second comment was to disprove 'you have filled the main page by old answered questions whereas relatively new questions become invisible?'. If you can't do it then no problem, I will change my way of editing questions/answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not at all, we do NOT have: $u^2 = x\implies du = dx $ What we do have is $$u^2 = x \implies 2 u \,du = dx.$$ That gets you $$\int  \sin{u}\,2u\,du = 2\int u\,\sin u \,du$$

Not a straightforward substitution whose integral you can immediately evaluate, though now you can use integration by parts.

---

ADDED from follow-up comments:

We let $w = u \implies dw = du$. We let $dv = \sin u\, du \implies v = \int \sin u \,du = -\cos u$. Now, we express: $$2(wv - \int v \,dw)$$

$$2\int u \,\sin u\, du = -2\Big(u \cos u - \int -\cos u \,du\Big) = -2u \cos u + 2\sin u + C$$

Now, simply back substitute $u = \sqrt x$, to get: $$-2\sqrt x \cos(\sqrt x) + 2\sin (\sqrt x) + C$$

---

**Note**: your updated answer is off on the coefficient of the $\sin$ term and it's argument: that term should be $$2 \sin (\sqrt x) \quad \text{or}\quad 2(\cdots + \sin \sqrt x)$$ And we do NOT differentiate (again) the term $\sqrt x$ to get $\dfrac 1{2\sqrt x}$, and certainly not $2\left(\cdots \dfrac 12 \sin\left(\frac x2\right)\right)$. We took care of the "chain rule" component when we put $u = \sqrt x \implies u^2 = x \implies 2u\,du = dx$. If we had chosen to find $du$ by differentiating $\sqrt x$, we'd  still have gotten $2u \,du = dx$:  $$u = \sqrt x \implies du = \dfrac 1{2\sqrt x}dx \iff 2\sqrt x du = dx \iff 2 u = dx$$ which was accounted for in our early substitution.

Comment: Effective one, Amy

Comment: Thanks amWhy! I'll get to work with the new info!

Comment: You're welcome, ConfusingCalc!

Comment: Quick Q, for the IBP, if I set $w = u$, $dw = du$, does $dv = sin(u)$? (making $v = -cos(\frac{u^2}{2})$

Comment: If $dv=\sin u du$ then $v=-\cos u$...

Comment: Do you see abiessu's correct answer? yes, $dv = \sin u$...so $v = \int dv = -\cos u...$

Comment: Why don't we integrate the u on it? (for some reason stack.exchange didn't notify me that you two replied). - sorry for the thousand questions

Comment: Because we want to get rid of the u! $$2\int u \,\sin u\, du = -2u \cos u - 2\int -\cos u \,du = -2u \cos u + 2\sin u + C$$ Now substitute $u = \sqrt x$.

Comment: I think that's what I got :) (edited in my original answer). Thanks bud! I wish I could hire you as a tutor for the semester.

Answer (score 2):

Careful!  $$\frac d{dx}u^2=2u\ du$$

Comment: Thanks Danny! I seem to make this mistakes often, I just need to pay closer attention and keep practicing. I'm working on this problem now :)